# Iterator member behavior

Tags: c++, class, pointers, stl, iterator

I was expecting the second assert in the following to pass.  I'm asking for your help.

**Edit:** It didn't work when I had poss everywhere instead of poss_a in some places.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

class Sampler
{
public:
 std::vector<int*> poss;
 std::vector<int*>::const_iterator poss_it;
 Sampler(std::vector<int*> poss_a) : poss(poss_a), poss_it(poss.begin())
 {
  assert( (poss[0]) == (*poss_it) ); //passes
 }
};

int main()
{
 int someInt;
 std::vector<int*> poss_a(1, &someInt);
 Sampler sampler(poss_a);
 assert( ((sampler.poss)[0]) == (*(sampler.poss_it)) ); //passes now

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about not mixing parameter and member names?

Comment: If you are going to edit your question, edit it to change the variable and parameter names, so that it is clearer what is what.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth -- if he does that -- it will work (meaning, that's his problem -- he's hiding the member with the parameter name)

Comment: @Lou Quite - I really don't know what he is trying to do here, and I've deleted my speculative answer, which I thought I already did. and as usual,  really crappy question gets upvotes. Sigh.

Comment: @drenami: If it's failing after you change it, you must have accidentally changed something else too. I just tested the code. It fails as you originally had it, but passes when you make the changes that I detailed in my answer. This is a copypasta of the program that compiles, runs, and passes both checks: http://pastebin.com/dPmtrm00

Comment: @Zylman: No, I was compiling the wrong file....  Now I'll learn never to name hide like that again.

Comment: @Alex We don't like pastebin here very much - post code as part of your answer.

Comment: @Neil I did post the code, in my answer. He was still having issues so I was showing him what the thing looks like as a whole. Should I have edited my post to show the entirety of the code?

Comment: @Alex If the code needs to be seen, then yes. The pastebin code will evaporate at some point, which makes the links on SO broken, and many lazy people (like me) simply won't bother opening another tab to look at it.

Comment: Well, it's fine then, because the code doesn't need to be seen. The code was just his code + the changes I said to make in my answer, so it's nothing new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `poss_it(poss.begin())` line in your initializer list is pulling an iterator from the poss that is the input to the constructor, not the one that is a field of the class.

This is a scope issue. When you're in the constructor, it's fine, because your iterator is a pointer to the input to the function. When you leave the constructor however, it's pointing to the same spot in memory but now you have no idea what's at that location.

You should change the name of the input variable in the constructor. You want one that does this:

```
Sampler(std::vector<int*> input) : poss(input), poss_it(poss.begin())
```

Whereas what your current one is doing is this:

```
Sampler(std::vector<int*> input) : poss(input), poss_it(input.begin())
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably getting confused over the local variables overriding the instance variables, try

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

class Sampler
{
public:
    std::vector<int*> poss;
    std::vector<int*>::const_iterator poss_it;
    // THIS IS THE LINE I CHANGED
    Sampler(std::vector<int*> aPoss)    : poss(aPoss), poss_it(poss.begin())
    {
        assert( (poss[0]) == (*poss_it) ); //passes
    }
};

int main()
{
    int someInt;
    std::vector<int*> poss(1, &someInt);
    Sampler sampler(poss);
    assert( ((sampler.poss)[0]) == (*(sampler.poss_it)) ); //fails

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because this->poss_it is an iterator into the argument and this->poss is a copy of the argument.  In the working assert, you are comparing the iterator to the arguments result from indexing, not this->poss.  Later you are comparing the iterator to this->poss.  It's confusing to explain because you use the variable name poss in three places -- in the constructor, the argument is hiding the member.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially invoking undefined behavior because `sampler.poss_it` is an iterator into a `std::vector<int*>` object that was destructed before the second `assert` was executed.

The problem was on the line:

```
Sampler(std::vector<int*> poss) : poss(poss), poss_it(poss.begin())
```

where the first `poss` of `poss(poss)` refers to the `Sampler` object's `poss` member, the second `poss` of `poss(poss)` refers to the `poss` parameter, and the `poss` of `poss_it(poss.begin())` refers again to the `poss` parameter (**not** the `poss` member). The `poss` parameter goes out of scope at the end of the constructor, so the `poss` parameter is destructed, meaning that the `poss_it` iterator is no longer valid.

To avoid this type of problem, C++ programmers almost always avoid shadowing variables. Also, a copy constructor should probably take a const-reference (to avoid pass-by-value for potentially large objects):

```
Sampler(const std::vector<int*>& poss_) : poss(poss_), poss_it(poss.begin())
```